# Cannot figure out specific regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm going to create a regexp for matching the following:

> The string should should consist of only lower case alpha-numeric characters (a-z) and a single '-' should be allowed within. For example, 'trash-bin' should be OK, however, 'trash--bin' or '-bin' should not.

How should the regexp look like? Also if it could be explained, I'd be happy.

This is what if have so far:

```
/^[0-9a-z]+-+$/

UPDATED TO:
```

^(?!\A-)+[0-9a-z]+-?$

What I don't know is how to disallow several - to follow each other, or disallow the string to begin with a -.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: php regex are well documented : http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: you can easily build your pattern here http://www.rubular.com/

Comment: what if '-' is not present or if '-' at the last?

Comment: `-+` is not at all what you want. That means "at least one `-`." If you want an optional `-`, that's indicated by `-?`. If you want a mandatory `-`, that's indicated by a simple `-`. Also, you need to indicate that alphanumerics are allowed after the `-` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)$
```

This may do the trick. Test it at http://www.regextester.com/ (select the *preg* dialect, as it is the one used by php's `preg_*` functions)

Comment: Numeric is missing from the Alphanumeric `[a-z0-9]`.

Comment: @ravz check twice you haven't the i (ignore-case) checkbox checked

Comment: @Korcholis guess you should add the `/i` in your answer. anyways +1. better answer

Comment: @ravz if I do so, then 898kGHJ-dsfg **definitely** accept. But that's not the point of this regex. In fact, I was talking about http://www.regextester.com/, having an `ignore-case` checkbox checked by default, and that needs to be unchecked to be the regex as intended.

Comment: The hyphen doesn't need escaping and capturing the line is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You want `^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$`:

```
$str=array("trash-bin","TRASH-Bin","232trash-bin","-trash-bin","trash","t--b");

foreach ($str as $val) {
  preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$/',$val,$match);
  echo $match[0];
}

>>> trash-bin
>>> 123trash-bin
>>> trash
```

Regexplanation:

```
^           # Match the start of the string
[a-z0-9]+   # Followed by one or more lowercase letter or digit
(-          # Followed by an hyphen
[a-z0-9]+   # Followed by one or more lowercase letter or digit 
)*          # Pattern inside brackets can occur zero or more times
$           # Followed by the end of the string
```

Comment: I was about to add explanation to my answer, no need now I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one hiphen and that too should be only between two or more charcaters(all small letters), then perhaps you can do away with following:

`^[a-z0-9]+-?[a-z0-9]+$`

Test it @ http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm .

Answer (score 0):

First find that the string starts with an alphanumeric, and continues for some length (one or more required match).

Then we start a subpattern so that we can make sure that *if* you do match a hyphen within the string, you also are required to match more alphanumerics following.

Within the subpattern allow for a single - (escape to avoid negating the following class)

Follow by some number of alphanumerics (one or more required match).
Close the subpattern.
[from your original question, it wasn't clear if ONLY a single dash should be allowed within the string, or if more than one might be allowed so long as they weren't contiguous. If multiples allowed then allow zero or more subpattern matches. Otherwise allow zero or one matches]

The pattern is then either:

`^([:alnum:]+(\-[:alnum:]+)?)$`

(for only a single dash allowed at all, or none) or

`^([:alnum:]+(\-[:alnum:]+)*)$`

For potentially multiple dashes but non-contiguous (i.e. no double dash)